# trying to show image on my jsp in war file format

Tags: jsp, struts2, jfreechart

i am making a web application which plots graph based on the date from database i use jfreechart and saving the graph as a image.And trying to display it on my jsp page by specifing the image path.

in jsp i am givin this

```
<img src="C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 7.0/webapps/yeargraph.jpg" class="myimageclass" alt="Graph Cannot be Displayed Due to some internal error"/>
```

inside my jfreechart program i give

```
String fileName="C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 7.0/webapps/yeargraph.jpg";
```

to save chart i am able to save the graph and display it on my jsp file if i run project in my eclipse Indigo but if i export it to a WAR file and paste WAR file in Tomcat/webapps/folder and then run brwoser "localhost:8080/projetcname/" i can see my project working fine But if I try to plot graph its is not showing the image in my jsp page y is it so am i doing something wrong pleas ehelp thanks in advance.

Note:Based the users input my application will generate different graphs by overwriting same image file so even this should be taken care of

Comment: Not clear, please try to re-explain the question better ,  `But if I try to plot graph its is not showing the image in my jsp page y is it so am i doing something wrong pleas ehelp thanks in advance` not clear

Comment: try and give the relative path to the file. that will work

Comment: try `<img src="../yeargraph.jpg" alt=""/>`

Comment: Mukul Goel,Sanket,aiwo99 thanks for ur help but my project works absolutely fine if i try to run it in eclipse IDE But if convert it into war and deploy it to tomcat i cant display the image on my jsp so i should try something like what goncaloGomes said.Thansk for ur help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have all kinds of problems when you deploy that to a production server. Try a different aproach:
- find a folder you know you will have permissions when in production;
- give jfreechart the path "[folder with permissions]/charts_temp_folder/yeargraph.jpg";
- write a small servlet to read the file and serve it;
- point your jsp to that folder;

Let us know how that goes.

Comment: goncaloGomes i only got partially what u said will try googling to implement it thanks

Answer (score 0):

To get the absolute file path by just searching for the file name you can try this

```
   String yeargraph= new ClassPathResource("yeargraph.jpg").getFile().getAbsolutePath();
```

Comment: its not path problem like goncaloGomes  said its something related to server as i covert projetc to WAR all my static image will kind of zipped into that WAR itself when i try to display the pages this zipped images from WAR will be shown but in my case i am having the Image file outside the WAR file and also this image is dynamically changing based on each request so i should some thing like what goncaloGomes said Thansk

Comment: and for that you will have to use this context path for finding the file path and serving it to page using servlet..

Comment: Sanket actually my time to do project is over iuu should submit it by monday willtry this if possible thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [Flot](http://www.flotcharts.org/) for web-based charting even over my own open source API [XChart](http://xeiam.com/xchart.jsp), which is geared more towards desktop applications. [Here](http://xeiam.com/helloflot.jsp) is a HelloWorld type example application with source code demonstrating Flot that I made at one point. If more you're more interested in fetching a JPEG containing a chart, you can see [how I do it with XChart](http://xeiam.com/xchart_examplecode.jsp) (Bonus Example, bottom of page), and you could probably do something very similar with `JFreeChart` without even needing to save the jpeg to disk first.